# In a light plasma, how many electrons pass through a given area

Tags: plasma-physics, space, sensor

Assume you have a light plasma of about 10^5 particles per cm^3. The energy-density of the plasma is about 0.1eV (as in near earth orbits, see here: http://assets.press.princeton.edu/chapters/s9500.pdf). If I have a satellite that passes through this plasma and has a faraday-cup as a sensor, how many electrons (and protons/positive ions) will be passing into the aperture so they could be counted? The faraday-cup is shielded with a fine mesh that has satellite ground potential. So no fields that would change the original trajectories of the particles should be seen outside the satellite.

The satellite has a speed of 8km/s (400km altitude) but electrons with 0.1eV already have a speed of 188km/s which renders the satellite almost standing still relative to the electrons. I know, that the plasma energy is just a mean value, but I think it is safe to assume that all electrons are way faster than the stallite.
So my questions: 1. How many charge carriers are expected to enter the aperture in a given time interval?
2. Is it a valid assumption that the satellite's speed is negligible?
Thanks everyone!

Comment: "light" is an ambiguous word in the title , you mean "in **a** light plasma"? Otherwise it sounds as  the electromagnetic light!

Comment: Yes, thanks. I changed it

Comment: I have several questions:  The electron thermal currents are going to dominate here, are they not?  Or is that what you meant by energy density (i.e., temperature of ~0.1 eV)?  Does the Faraday cup (FC) have an electrostatic deflection grid to separate ions from electrons?  FCs are basically glorified ammeters so unless you filter out one or the other species, you will not get an accurate measure of the plasma.

Comment: @honeste_vivere Yes, 0.1eV is the "temperature". The FC has at least one deflection grid: the one (to space) has 0V relative to the satelite and the measuring electrode inside is positive to only allow electrons to arrive there. So from the outside the aperture does not produce a electrical field in order to not affect the outside plasma. Only electrons that "enter on their own" should be measured. My question is: How many electrons will be entering with the given assumed values for plasma temperature and particle density.

Comment: If you ignore bulk flow speeds, then just consider thermal currents and calculate the total current density of the electrons.  Then integrate over the opening area of the cup to get the total current, i.e., total charge per unit time.  After that it's pretty simple to find the total number of electrons...

Comment: Hey, thanks, can you hint me at a resource where I can read about this? Much appreciated, you almost solved my problem.